# Parameterized invoking of notebooks does not work

Tags: azure-synapse, azure-synapse-analytics

I am trying to run multiple notebooks from the data we have, so I am using for each and @item().NotebookName. However, Synapse is failing, it can't find the notebook, even though notebook name is clearly the same as the value passed. Am I missing something? These notebooks are still in my branch. I guess I will need to use mssparkutils.notebook.run

[image: pipelinePic]

[image: insidepipeline]

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Perhaps these notebooks only exist in your branch, and you run in trigger mode and not in debug mode?

Comment: @Aswin that is the thing, there is none. Just the red one, but there is no issue, either when running or validating. It might be a bug

Comment: @ChenHirsh I am running in debug, not triggering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**One possible reason is, when you are invoking the notebook where notebook name specified with a dynamic expression, the particular notebook should be published** prior to that or else it will give the below error.

[image]

Here, I got same error when notebook name given through dynamic expression and notebook was not published.

[image]

It will identify the unpublished notebooks only when we are giving the notebook from the dropdown.

[image]

**So, publish all your notebooks before the pipeline execution** and then debug the pipeline. Now, it will identify the notebook from the dynamic expression.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I discovered that today. Thanks